# Display a "Details" view as a modal popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have this code to show info about a certain product registered in my database.

> Button that triggers my Details Controller:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = prod.ID }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" }) |
```

> Controller code

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        PRODUCTS pRODUCTS = db.PRODUCTS.Find(id);
        if (pRODUCTS == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(pRODUCTOS);
    }
```

I want to display that "Details" view in a modal popup. I tried to create my modal in the same view where i have my "Details" button, but i can't pass my product id to the controller and it only shows me an empty view.

Comment: You have a link that makes a redirect (it does not display a modal in the same view - to do that you need to use ajax to call a server method that returns a partial view or `JsonResult` and update the DOM).

Answer (score 0):

To show data inside a modal popup, you need an action method which returns HTML markup needed for the modal popup. So the first step is to make an action method which returns a partial view result.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var product = db.PRODUCTS.Find(id);
    if (product== null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(product);
}
```

In the above simple example, I am querying the entity and passing the entity object directly to my view using the `PartialView` method. If you have a view model for your view, please use that.

Now in the `Details.cshtml` view, we will write code to return the [HTML markup needed for the modal popup](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo). Since we are passing the `PRODUCTS` object to the view, we will make sure our view is also strongly typed to that type.

```
@model YourNamespaceHere.PRODUCTS 

<div id="modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title"> Details</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h2>Hello from @Model.Name</h2>    
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above example, I am simply printing the `Name` property value of `PRODUCTS` object in the modal body. You may update it to render other properties as needed.

Now we will make some changes to our HTML markup being rendered for the product. We need the `click` event on the details link to open the modal dialog. So let's first give some attributes to the link element, which we can later use to wireup the click event. Here I am going to add an additional CSS class to the links, `modal-link`.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = prod.ID }, 
                                       new { @class = "btn modal-link" })
```

Now let's write some JavaScript code to listen to the `click` event on the link element with the `modal-link` CSS class, read the the `href` attribute value of the element and make an Ajax call to that URL and render the response of that call to build the modal dialog.

```
$(function () {

    $('body').on('click', 'a.modal-link', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $("#modal").remove();

        // Get the Details action URL
        var url = $(this).attr("href");

        //Make the Ajax call and render modal when response is available
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $(data).modal();
        });
    }); 

});
```

I am using CSS class as the selector here, you can use any other selector as you wish

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use jquery ajax to call action on click your button or action link and get your model as json result and return it  then first clean your modal data and fill it with new result and at the end show your modal......